# Create different `randperm` numbers in loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, random

Suppose that we have this structure:

```
for i=1:x1
Out = randperm(40);
Out_Final = %% divide 'Out' to 10 parts. and select these parts for some purposes

for j=1:x2

%% Process on `Out_Final`

end
end
```

I'm using outer loop (`for i=1:x1`) to repeat main process `(for j=1:x2) loop` and average between outputs to have more robust results. I want `randperm` doesn't result equal (or near equal) outputs. I want have different Output for this function as far as possible in every calling in `(for i=1:x1)` loop.

How can i do that in `MATLAB R2014a`?

Comment: randperm(40) has about 8.15915283247898e+47 different possible outputs, each with (about) the same probability of being returned. This means that even if you run your program for your entire lifetime, you probably will not get the same permutation twice. So you need to specify what you mean by near equal!

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jens. So what is purpose of `rng` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The randomness algorithms used by `randperm` are very good. So, don't worry about that.

However, if you draw 10 random numbers from 1 to 10, you are likely to see some more frequently than others.

If you REALLY don't want this, you should probably not focus on randomly selecting the numbers, but on selecting the numbers in a way that they are nicely spread out througout their possible range. (This is a quite different problem to solve).

---

To address your comment:

The `rng` function allows you to create reproducible results, make sure to check `doc rng` for examples.

In your case it seems like you actually don't want to reset the `rng` each time, as that would lead to correlated random numbers.

Comment: Thank your Dennis. So what is purpose of 'rng' function?

Comment: @user2991243 Updated the answer, basically you don't need it unless you actually want to draw the same random numbers multiple times.